# Hibernate generating it's own join table when I specified one

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have specified a `@JoinTable` for a `@ManyToMany` so that I can specify names for the table, columns, and foreign keys.

Hibernate seems to be generating mine properly, but it still attempts to generate it's own as well.

---

Here's the Entity with the `@ManyToMany` in question. Only included relevant code from the entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DAMAGE")
public class DamageReport {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "DAMAGE_ID_GENERATOR")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "DAMAGE_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "DAMAGE_ID_SQ")
    @Column(name = "DAMAGE_ID")
    private Long id;

    //...Bunch of other fields

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "BOARD_MEMBER_DAMAGE_REPORTS", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "DAMAGE_REPORT_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "BOARD_MEMBER_ID") }, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "DAMAGE_REPORT_ID_FK"), inverseForeignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "BOARD_MEMBER_ID_FK"))
    private Set<BoardMember> boardMembers;
}
```

---

Here is the other Entity in the `@ManyToMany`. Only included relevant code from the entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BOARD_MEMBER")
public class BoardMember {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "BOARD_MEMBER_ID_GENERATOR")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "BOARD_MEMBER_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "BOARD_MEMBER_ID_SQ")
    @Column(name = "BOARD_MEMBER_ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    public Set<DamageReport> damageReports;
}
```

---

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mappedBy on another side to complete the bidirectional mapping:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "boardMembers")
public Set<DamageReport> damageReports;
```

Comment: Wow. That was simple. Thankyou! - Is there a reason I can't add that on the `DamageReport` side?

Comment: Yes there is. In bidirectional mapping, there must always be one owner side (DamageReport in this case) and another side(BoardMember) must **only** references the owner side (with mappedBy = "boardMembers").